# How to Select Duplicated DIV IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs, the second was cloned from the first using:

```
function dupe() {
var cc = document.getElementById("cc"); // original
var cc2 = cc.cloneNode(true); // clone
cc.parentNode.appendChild(cc2);
$('#cc :input').attr('disabled', true);
document.getElementById("cc").style.opacity = "0.5"; // affects original, which is fine
document.getElementById("radioNew").checked = true; // affects original, but needs to affect clone
}
```

However, this line does not affect the clone, but rather the original, like the line above it:

```
document.getElementById("radioNew").checked = true;
```

Since the clone has the same IDs, how can I select the IDs in the clone? Would I have to create a function to rename all of the IDs in the clone?

Comment: You should rename the clone, since having the same id is not valid html

Comment: Also you can use CSS class to achieve what you want.

Comment: Try to only use Jquery when you use it or only JS. Instead of `document.getElementById()` you can use `$("#yourid")`

Comment: @Alexis ...what?

Comment: @j08691 just a tip not an error. He's using Jquery for some selection and for other selection/manipulation he'is using pureJS... That's better to only use one of them no  ? For a solution more readable and maintanable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this properly with ids, you would need to change all id properties in all the nested nodes, since you create a "deep" clone.

When you really need to clone nodes like this, I would recommend not identifying nodes by their id but by some other selector, like a CSS (pseudo-)class. This is rather easy using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<!-- Note: class attributes instead of id -->
<div class="cc">
    <div class="radioNew">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var original = $('.cc');
var clone = original.clone();

original.find('.radioNew').attr( ... );    <--- finds subelement of original
clone.find('.radioNew').attr( ... );       <--- finds subelement of clone
```